# Are there extensions of publication-bias tests for Network Meta-Analysis?

Tags: network-meta-analysis, publication-bias

In pairwise meta-analysis, it is common to check for publication bias. In particular, there are multiple tests for funnel-plot asymmetry (see here for Cochrane's recommendations about that: https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_10/10_4_3_1_recommendations_on_testing_for_funnel_plot_asymmetry.htm)

Has anyone ever proposed an extension of them to Network Meta-Analysis?